# Prove identity by induction

Tags: analysis, induction, self-learning

Recently I read in lecture notes that for $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^m$ with $\vert\alpha\vert = r$ the following identity holds: 
$$ \sum_{} \frac{1}{\alpha!} = \frac{m^r}{r!}.$$

Appearently one can prove that by induction. I tried but did not succeed. How to prove this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your identity is a simple consequence of the multinomial theorem.
For $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)\in\mathbb{N}^m$ we write $x^\alpha:=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_m^{\alpha_m}$ (and, as you do, $|\alpha|:=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_m$, $\alpha!:=\alpha_1!\cdots\alpha_m!$). Then
\begin{equation*}
(x_1+\cdots+x_m)^r
\,=\, \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^m\!,\,|\alpha|=r}\frac{r!}{\alpha!}\,x^\alpha~.
\end{equation*}
You obtain your identity taking $x_1=\cdots=x_m=1$. Now of course you must prove the multinomial theorem. You will find that proving the multinomial theorem requires precisely as much effort and ingenuity as proving your very special identity. Or, you may simply accept the multinomial theorem as well-known.

Comment: Thanks, this is even more general!

Comment: @Taufi - You can prove the multinomial theorem by induction, using the binomial theorem as known. Try doing this yourself; if you find yourself banging your head against the wall for too long, cheat a little and peek into the Wikipedia article on multinomial theorem.

Comment: Of course given that the OP didn't _recognize_ a simple explicit application of the _binomial_ theorem as such this seems... never mind, can't put my finger on the right word.

Comment: Thanks so much, chizhek. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an induction on $m$. Suppose the result holds for $\Bbb N^m$. For $\alpha\in\Bbb N^{m+1}$write $$\alpha=(\alpha',\beta),$$where $\alpha'\in\Bbb N^m$ and $\beta\in\Bbb N$. Then
$$\sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb N^{m+1},|\alpha|=r}\frac{1}{\alpha!}
=\sum_{\beta=0}^r\frac1{\beta!}\sum_{\alpha'\in\Bbb N^m,|\alpha'|=r-\beta}
\frac{1}{(\alpha')!}=\sum_{\beta=0}^r\frac{m^{r-\beta}}{\beta!(r-\beta)!}
=\frac{(m+1)^r}{r!}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems correct, however, could you make the the last step of calculation more transparent? Also, and this might be embarrasing to ask, I do not get why the induction start, e.g. for $m=1$, $\sum_{} \frac{1}{\alpha!} = \frac{1}{r!}$? Is this some elementary result of analysis that I do'nt know?

Comment: The last step is a standard elementary theorem that says $(m+1)^r$ equals something. The case $m=1$ is _trivial_. Think about it.

Comment: @Taufi It is probably easy to start with $m=1$ and starting with $m=0$ Has problems for some values of $r$.

Comment: I am sure it is $\textit{trivial}$ but I have to have some error in my thinking. In case of $m=1$, that is $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, I thought it would follow $\sum_{\alpha = 1}^{r} \frac{1}{\alpha!} = \frac{1}{r!}$, but this cannot hold true but I do not see the flaw here.

Comment: $\sum_{\alpha=1}^r\frac{1}{\alpha!}$ has absolutely nothing to do with it. You need to get straight exactly what the problem asks you to prove.

Comment: I think that in the case of $m=1$ it is $\alpha = r = 1$ otherwise I run into the trouble above. Is that what you meant? If not, I don't get exactly the deeper nature of the problem you seem to insinuate.

Comment: $\alpha=r=1$ is half right. I don't see what's not to get about my previous comment, or why you take it as an "insinuation". _If_ you think(thought) that the sum in your previous comment has something to do with the problem then you don't(didn't) understand what the problem is asking you to prove. Is that clearer?

Comment: You misread my comment. I get your $\textit{comment}$, however, I did not get the deeper nature that your comments would seem to point at. But nevermind, I will figure it out on my own now.